# Using picture tag in React without loading excessive amounts of data in the browser

Tags: reactjs, image, webp

I'm using the `picture` tag to load `webp` images by default, and `jpg` images if the `webp` can't load. This is how I'm doing it ([also on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-curie-dnyg7?file=/src/App.js:0-374))

```
import jpg from "./jake-the-dog.jpg";
import webp from "./jake-the-dog.webp";

export default () => (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      <picture>
        <source srcSet={webp} type="image/webp" />
        <img src={jpg} type="image/jpg" />
      </picture>

    </div>
);
```

What concerns me about this method is that I'm importing both images into the component, so doesn't that mean I'm importing almost twice as much data? (the jpg and the webp) or am I wrong about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing two images, but the browser requested the second image `jake-the-dog.webp`, I verified this by using the network tab:

[image]

If the image `jake-the-dog.webp` failed to load, the browser will request the first image `jake-the-dog.jpg`